# How can I go and grab Graphic thats in Main from my method?

Tags: java, string, methods, graphic

I am trying to put a method inside main but it won't compile because graphics "g" can't be found in method.

Error message:

```
Lab5.java:66: error: method convert in class Lab5 cannot be applied to given types;
        convert(g);
        ^
  required: String
  found: Graphics
  reason: actual argument Graphics cannot be converted to String by method invocation conversion
Lab5.java:93: error: cannot find symbol
        A.drawString(accord, 300, 100);    }
         ^
  symbol:   method drawString(String,int,int)
  location: variable A of type String
2 errors
```

Code:

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
    DrawingPanel2 panel = new DrawingPanel2(WIDTH, HEIGHT);
    panel.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
    Graphics g = panel.getGraphics();

    //  Sample line of code, showing how to display a picture from a JPG file
        drawPicture(g, panel, "240sx.jpg", 0, 0, WIDTH, HEIGHT);

    g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
    Scanner termIn = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("User, please give me a string to print:\n\t");
    String in = termIn.nextLine();

    //first string code
    String s1 = in;
    String civic = s1.replace("car","karr").replace("cool","crazy")
    .replace("the","teh").replace("red","blue").replace("kouki","cookie")
    .replace("nissan","datsun").replace("s14","silvia").replace("drift","slide")
    .replace("laugh","LOL").replace("240sx","sr20").replace("drive","shift");


    System.out.println(civic);
    g.drawString(civic, 60, 259);


    //second string code
    //Scanner termIn2 = new Scanner(System.in);
    //System.out.print("User, please give me a string to print:\n\t");
    //String honda = termIn2.nextLine();


    //String s2 = honda;
    //String accord = s2.replace("car","karr").replace("cool","crazy")
    //.replace("the","teh").replace("red","blue").replace("kouki","cookie")
    //.replace("nissan","datsun").replace("s14","silvia").replace("drift","slide")
    //.replace("laugh","LOL").replace("240sx","sr20").replace("drive","shift");


    //System.out.println(accord);
    //g.drawString(accord, 300, 100);
    convert(g);




    //attribution for original photographer
    g.drawString("Dax Rodriguez", 0, HEIGHT - FONTSIZE);
        }

//Methods


//replace a word within a sentence
public static String convert(String A) {
    Scanner termIn2 = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("User, please give me a string to print:\n\t");
    String honda = termIn2.nextLine();


    String s2 = honda;
    String accord = s2.replace("car","karr").replace("cool","crazy")
    .replace("the","teh").replace("red","blue").replace("kouki","cookie")
    .replace("nissan","datsun").replace("s14","silvia").replace("drift","slide")
    .replace("laugh","LOL").replace("240sx","sr20").replace("drive","shift");

    System.out.println(accord);
    A.drawString(accord, 300, 100);

}
```

Comment: Just copy and paste your code in to the edit window, and **make sure it is formatted properly** so its easier for us to read. Click the little `{}` icon in the edit window to set it in a code block. Also, if you mean putting a method inside your `main` method, you cannot put a method inside of a method, that doesn't make sense in Java.

Comment: not a method inside a method but from main i am calling a method and somehow graphics won't go into the method

Comment: Ah ok, understood. The wording confused me. Once you post the code we'll be able to see.

Comment: ok got i got the code up, and please I'm new to this so i need all the help i can get

Answer (score 1):

When you say `convert(g);`, `g` is of type `Graphics`. `convert` currently takes a `String` object, not a `Graphics` object, which is why you get an error.

Also, `convert` doesn't return anything, so you should replace `String` with `void`.

Changing this:

```
public static String convert(String A) {
```

to this:

```
public static void convert(Graphics A) {
```

should fix your errors.

Comment: thanks so much, but i have another question, what does a "return" do? I'm not quite clear on that.

Comment: To the OP: watch out for simple errors like this. Object types are not arbitrary; if a method says its accepts a `String` parameter, no other object type other than a `String` or one of its subtypes will do (small caveat to further confuse you: Strings are marked as `final` and cannot be extended by potential subclasses, but apply my statement to general object types and hopefully you'll understand what I mean).

Comment: @user3357247 Your convert method is "public static **String** convert", so it should return a string. Returning a string with `return "this is a string"` makes `convert(g)` have a value of `"this is a string"`, so `System.out.println(convert(g));` will print out `this is a string`. Given the context in which you used `convert`, I think you don't want it to return anything, so you should change `public static String convert` to `public static void convert`.